# Cannot seem to click on and highlight selected li once it is renamed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I can't seem to wrap my head around this problem and to figure it out properly. Logically, I should be able to click on and select the new li that has just been renamed. This is not the case though. Currenty, I am able to click on and to select any LI and it will become highlighted. Once I click on the rename button, and then click on the newly renamed li, the background color does not change but the rest still appear to work (the li's that have not been renamed). I have attached a pic of the problem below:

[image]

Here is the HTML markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>

<style type='text/css'>

.active {
    background-color: rgb(128,128,128);
}
#colors {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 100px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: arrow;
}
</style>



<script type='text/javascript'>

function renameLI() {

    var li = $('#colors').find('.active')

    li.replaceWith('<input type="text" id="change_me" value='+li.text()+'>');

}

$(window).load(function(){


    $('li').click(function(){

        $('li.active').removeClass('active');

        $(this).addClass('active');

    });


    $('#colors').focusout(function() {

        $('#change_me').replaceWith('<li>' + $("#change_me").val() + '</li>');

    });


});

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="raname" id="rename" onclick="renameLI()">
<ul id="colors">
    <li>red</li>
    <li>green</li>
    <li>blue</li>
    <li>yellow</li>
    <li>orange</li>
    <li>purple</li>
</ul>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: You are missing a ';' after `find('.active')

Comment: What if you use html() instead of replaceWith() ?

Comment: @RubyRacer JavaScript statements don't require semicolons. But yes, it's a good idea IMO to use them.

Comment: It took me 5 years to realize ;)... thanks @mikehomme

Comment: @RubyRacer Probably because no one ever leaves them out, unless it's by accident. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use html() instead of replaceWith().

```
$(function () {

    $("#rename").on("click", function(){
        var li = $('#colors').find('.active');
        li.html('<input type="text" id="change_me" value='+li.text()+'>');
    });

    $('li').on("click", function () {
        $('li.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    $('#colors').on("focusout", function () {
        $('#change_me').replaceWith('<li>' + $("#change_me").val() + '</li>');
    });
});
```

Here's a working **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/occursys/p50gwskh/)**

I also cleaned up your click() with on() and removed your onclick in HTML to your jQuery code.

Comment: Almost there! and thanks for this. But it seems that the input box is never removed and lingers. What could be wrong? Im using IE 11.

Comment: Sorry, I goofed up the fiddle yesterday. I updated it and adjusted the code above. I was calling html() on focus out and should have been on the rename click.

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching an event listener to the `li` and then removing it with `replaceWith`. That is a new DOM element at that point and has no listener.

Use

`$(document).on('click','li',function(){`

Read: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Long Answer:

With `$('li').click(function(){` you are saying hey DOM, when you are ready take all the `li`s and if they get clicked on, do this function. And the DOMs like, ok, let me find all those and registers a listener to each one. Then you're like `$('#change_me').replaceWith('<li>' + $("#change_me").val() + '</li>');` Boom, that `li` is gone and here is a new one. And poor old DOM doesn't even know that one exists.

So when you delegate that listener to `$(document)` you are saying, he document, if you see any `li`s get clicked on do this function. And even when you add a new `li`, and that `li` gets clicked on, `$(document)` is all, hey, I saw that through event propagation, let's do that function. All events bubble from where they started up to the top level of the document.